# Send image as attachment as well as inline using Sendgrid API

Tags: php, image, api, curl, sendgrid

I want to send an email with the image as an attachment and also embed it in the body.

```
<?php
$email = "to@example.com";
$name = "some_name";
$img = file_get_contents('image.jpg');
$body = '<img src = "cid:image">';
$subject = "Test email";

      

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer API_KEY',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$data = array(
    "personalizations" => array(
        array(
            "to" => array(
                array(
                    "email" => $email,
                    "name" => $name
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    "from" => array(
        "email" => "from@example.com"
    ),
    "subject" => $subject,
    "content" => array(
        array(
            "type" => "text/html",
            "value" => $body
        )
    ),

    "attachments" => array(
        array(
            "content" => base64_encode($img),
            "type" => "image/jpeg",
            "filename" => "image",
            "disposition" => "inline",
            "content_ID" => "image",
            //"disposition" => "attachment"
        )
    )         
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;?>
```

The problem is that it is either going as inline content or an attachment but not both. I don't know how to solve this.
I tried adding two separate **attachments** blocks for inline and attachment, but it's always considering the second block.
Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

You don't want to set two of the same keys in an `array` (as you are doing for `disposition`) or set two `attachments` blocks. Instead, you should add two items to the `attachments` block, like this:

```php
    "attachments" => array(
        array(
            "content" => base64_encode($img),
            "type" => "image/jpeg",
            "filename" => "image-inline",
            "disposition" => "inline",
            "content_ID" => "image-inline",
        ),
        array(
            "content" => base64_encode($img),
            "type" => "image/jpeg",
            "filename" => "image-attachment",
            "disposition" => "attachment",
            "content_ID" => "image-attachment",
        ),
    )
```

Notice I also provided different filenames and content IDs for the inline and attached files.

Comment: I can't use different file names because files are being automatically downloaded from a website at an interval with the same name. In other words, Different files are downloaded automatically and each time the previous image is replaced with the new image.

Comment: But you could prefix or suffix that filename, right?

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that?  I may be asking a silly question but I am new to this and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Looking at your code, I don't think this actually matters much. You can just call the filename "image-inline" or "image-attachment" like I did in the code above, right? Have you tried to run it like that?